# Anaconda Error : 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: anaconda

[image: My code]

I am new in this field. I tried to follow a youtube tutorial. I did everything they do, but when I tried clone GitHub repo, it says, "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

What should I do now?

Comment: Are you sure you have Git installed?

Comment: I am not sure. The youtube tutorial shows nothing about installing git!

Comment: Still having the problem even after installing git.